# React Native issues with Sdk

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native project I am trying to run with `npm run android`. The project starts, launches the emulator then stops, when I try to reload, it says `warn: No devices connected.....` even though the emulator is running.
Now for debugging I made sure all my paths are declared correctly and even reinstalled Android Studio with all the tools.

I tried `npx react-native doctor`
[image] but it failed. the cli admits to android_home path exisiting but apparently turns a blind eye towards the exisiting sdk tools even though they do exist. Kindly help

I have cleaned cache, including forcing. verified the installations but no fruits

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have to add the tools to your path in ~/.zshrc

open ~/.zshrc with `nano ~/.zshrc` (or some other text editor) (I believe you can also add them to bash_profile)

add something like this:

```
# Android SDK
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.2
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Android/platform-tools"
```

Of course check that the files you are referring to in the locations you specify, with those same versions. If they are not, you'll need to install them via Android studio, but it sounds like you have done that already.

If you already have something like this, kindly share it, because I think the issue is in these paths.